# Python 2.7 error: Indentation error

Tags: python, indentation

I am working with an example file of a Tkinter layout. I keep getting an error that is boggling my mind.

the code worked until I inserted the statements:

```
area.pack() 
area.insert(end, "hello")
```

then I got the error:

```
Indentation error: unexpected indentation.
```

ok, so I commented the two statements out (as shown below), to get what is essentially the exact same code I started with, which worked fine- only to keep getting the same error again. I have played around with it for a few hours now and I simply can't grasp the - im sure- really simple thing that is really triggering this. Any thoughts?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
ZetCode Tkinter tutorial

In this script, we use the grid
manager to create a more complicated
layout.

author: Jan Bodnar
last modified: December 2010
website: www.zetcode.com
"""

from Tkinter import Tk, Text, BOTH, W, N, E, S
from ttk import Frame, Button, Label, Style


class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   

        self.parent = parent

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("Windows")
        self.style = Style()
        self.style.theme_use("default")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(3, pad=7)
        self.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(5, pad=7)

        lbl = Label(self, text="Windows")
        lbl.grid(sticky=W, pady=4, padx=5)

        area = Text(self)
        area.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=4, 
            padx=5, sticky=E+W+S+N)

        #area.pack()    
        #area.insert(end, "hello")

        abtn = Button(self, text="Activate")
        abtn.grid(row=1, column=3)

        cbtn = Button(self, text="Close")
        cbtn.grid(row=2, column=3, pady=4)

        hbtn = Button(self, text="Help")
        hbtn.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=5)

        obtn = Button(self, text="OK")
        obtn.grid(row=5, column=3)        


def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("350x300+300+300")
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Run the script with `python -tt`.  It's likely that you've accidentally mixed tabs with spaces.

Comment: Have you checked the indentation of your code?

Comment: Inspecting the code in the question edit view definitely shows mixed tabs and spaces. Turn on "show whitespace" in your editor, or if your editor doesn't support that, use one that does.

Comment: Look at what you pasted into the editor. Namely, `#area.pack()`.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing tabs and spaces.  Don't do that :-) <sup>1</sup>

For future reference, run the code with `python -tt` instead of just `python`<sup>2</sup>.  If you mix tabs and spaces `python -tt` will yell at you and tell you to fix it rather than giving strange indentation errors.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Don't do that in any language.  It only leads to pain and suffering.</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup>I believe that this is the default behavior for python3.x.</sup>

Comment: I managed to fix it by pasting the code into python and untabbifying it ...